# Using replace in select clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Trying to use the `REPLACE` to rename the start and end of the string. The string that I have is, for example: `ABCD - [001]`. I wanto to get just the `001` and count.

Example: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99e73/2)

The result should be:

```
Description  Total
        001      4
        002      2
        003      3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description fields (at least in the example) all have the numbers in the same position.  So, the easiest way to get them is `substring()`:

```
SELECT (case when Description LIKE '%/[___/]%' ESCAPE '/' then substring(description, 9, 3)
             else Description
        end) as Description,
        COUNT (*) AS Total
FROM Table1
WHERE Description LIKE '%/[___/]%' ESCAPE '/' OR Description LIKE '___'
GROUP BY (case when Description LIKE '%/[___/]%' ESCAPE '/' then substring(description, 9, 3)
               else Description
          end)
ORDER BY Description ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked in the test and the real cenario

Comment: the fields changed a little bit. Now there is some random text in between. Can you please help me figure it out again? This is the new fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4120/2

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99e73/25)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 
  (
    Description varchar(20)
  );

INSERT INTO Table1
  (
    Description
  )

VALUES
  ('ABCD - [001]'),('ABCD - [001]'),('XIo9 - [001]'),('001'),
  ('XYZW - [002]'),('002'),('XYZW - [003]'),('XYZW - [003]'),('003');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
    RIGHT(REPLACE(REPLACE(RIGHT('0000' + Description,4), '[', ''),']',''),3) Description,
    COUNT (*) AS Total
FROM
    Table1
GROUP BY
    RIGHT(REPLACE(REPLACE(RIGHT('0000' + Description,4), '[', ''),']',''),3)
ORDER BY
    Description ASC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99e73/25/0)**:

```
| DESCRIPTION | TOTAL |
|-------------|-------|
|         001 |     4 |
|         002 |     2 |
|         003 |     3 |
```

Comment: I just want the numbers inside the []. Thanks.

Comment: In that case Gordon Linoff has answered your question.

Comment: @Khrys I have also updated my answer, have a look now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `CASE WHEN LEN(Description)=3 THEN Description ELSE SUBSTRING(Description, 9, 3) END` to select the description column.

Your query should look like

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN LEN(Description)=3 THEN Description ELSE SUBSTRING(Description, 9, 3) END as Description,
    COUNT (*) AS Total
FROM
    Table1
WHERE
    Description LIKE '%/[___/]%' ESCAPE '/' OR Description LIKE '___'
GROUP BY
    Description
ORDER BY
    Description ASC
```